# How to allow an OG group admin to create and add a user to a group?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users, authentication-authorization

I have a situation where our D7 site is connected to a LDAP server (with [LDAP](https://drupal.org/project/ldap)) module. However, I need a way to allow an [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) administrator to add a user (who has not yet logged in) and automatically enroll that user in that same group.

How might I address this?

My first thought is to just build a form where the OG admin adds the user name to a queue. When that user finally logs in, I would use the user_save() hook to add them to the appropriate group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a round about way. I made my own form with two values and a `user_access('administer group')` check. The first value is the group id and the second is the user name.

In the `myform_form_submit()`, if the user name exists in the users table, I run `og_group` to subscribe that user. If the username does not exists and the user has not logged in, I add them to a queue as a key value pair of username and group id.

When the user logs in, hook_user_login() searches through that queue to find any instance and if so, subscribes them to that group.